# Разобраться в ассемблерном коде

Tags: ассемблер

Есть функция на ассемблере, она неким образом хеширует строку. Хотелось бы понять, что именно она делает. Я примерно представляю что она делает, но не догоняю сути. Вот исходный код и содержимое регистров:

*Исходный код*
[image: code]

*Содержимое регистров в начале*
[image: begin]

*Содержимое регистров в конце*
[image: end]

Результатом является число в регистре EAX. Я понимаю, что в начале и конце программы проверяется конец строки, каждое следующее значение зависит от предыдущего.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Очень похоже на обычный CRC-32. Такой используется, например, в [gzip(самый низ спецификации)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt) и [png](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-CRCAppendix.html).

Comment: Плюсую, очень похоже на вот этот кусок:

    for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
          c = crc_table[(c ^ buf[n]) & 0xff] ^ (c >> 8);

Comment: Не понимаю только где наложение битовой маски ( & 0xff) в ассмеблерном листинге, а в остальном один сдвиг и два XOR очень похоже на правду.

Comment: @igumnov, там и c и buf[n] байтовые, так что маску налагать не нужно.

Comment: `MOVZX EAX,AL` это и есть наложение `0xff`

Comment: @KaZaца, это добивание байтового значения слева нулями до 4 байт. Наложение маски возможно было убрано компилятором вследствие оптимизации, т.к. наложение этой маски на байтовую переменную никак ее не изменяет.

Answer (score 6):

Что мы имеем:

Функция получает 3 параметра - 2 через стек, еще один через регистр ECX. Похоже на [thiscall](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%EE%E3%EB%E0%F8%E5%ED%E8%E5_%E2%FB%E7%EE%E2%E0#thiscall).

В ECX лежит указатель на строку, в одном из стековых параметров еще один указатель на строку, в другом - указатель на ее конец.

Вот этот код:

```
cmp EDX, b
jnb l2
l1:
...
cmp EDX, b
jb l1
l2:
```

эквивалентен `while(EDX<b) {...}`

Также функция обращается к области памяти по адресу 1111FD0h. Очевидно, там находится массив из 256 двойных слов. Все остальное должно стать достаточно понятным, если попробовать переписать в псевдокоде.